# Apache Spark: using spark-submit to transfer files from windows to cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- using `spark-submit` to submit a packaged / compiled (using `sbt 0.13.12`) scala programm to my virtualized "cluster" running [hdp 2.4](https://de.hortonworks.com/products/data-center/hdp/) (Spark 1.6.0, Scala 2.10.5) using virtual box
- using the `--files` option to copy a text file "foo.txt" (which is located in the project root) from the "submitting" Windows machine (which is also running Spark 1.6.0 and Scala 2.10.5) to the working directories of executors (as described by `spark-submit -h`)
- passing the textfile as first argument to my application
- finally: reading in the file and counting the lines

The command for submitting is

```
spark-submit ^
--class boern.spark.SparkMeApp ^
--master "spark://127.0.0.1:7077" ^
--files "foo.txt" ^
target/scala-2.11/sparkme-project_2.11-1.0.jar foo.txt
```

The interesting part of code is

```
val fileName = args(0)
println(s"argument 0 is $fileName")
val lines = sc.textFile(fileName).cache
val c = lines.count /** line 37 */
```

The error (short version) I'm getting is:

```
INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: count at SparkMeApp.scala:37, Exception, Job aborted: java
.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist
```

After two days of a combination "bruteforcing" and reading documentation I am still lost... Am I wrong, that `sc.textFile(fileName).cache` is executed on the workers and everything which is not preceeded by `sc` on master? Is using [`SparkFiles`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.html) the way to go?

Stacktrace

```
E:\myProject\>spark-submit --verbose --class boern.spark.SparkMeApp --master "spark://127.0.0.1:7077" --files "foo.txt" target/scala-2.11/sparkme-project_2.11-1.0.jar foo.txt 
Using properties file: null
Parsed arguments:
  master                  spark://127.0.0.1:7077
  deployMode              null
  executorMemory          null
  executorCores           null
  totalExecutorCores      null
  propertiesFile          null
  driverMemory            null
  driverCores             null
  driverExtraClassPath    null
  driverExtraLibraryPath  null
  driverExtraJavaOptions  null
  supervise               false
  queue                   null
  numExecutors            null
  files                   file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt
  pyFiles                 null
  archives                null
  mainClass               boern.spark.SparkMeApp
  primaryResource         file:/E:/myProject/target/scala-2.11/sparkme-project_2.11-1.0.jar
  name                    boern.spark.SparkMeApp
  childArgs               [foo.txt]
  jars                    null
  packages                null
  packagesExclusions      null
  repositories            null
  verbose                 true

Spark properties used, including those specified through
 --conf and those from the properties file null:



Main class:
boern.spark.SparkMeApp
Arguments:
foo.txt
System properties:
SPARK_SUBMIT -> true
spark.files -> file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt
spark.app.name -> boern.spark.SparkMeApp
spark.jars -> file:/E:/myProject/target/scala-2.11/sparkme-project_2.11-1.0.jar
spark.submit.deployMode -> client
spark.master -> spark://127.0.0.1:7077
Classpath elements:
file:/E:/myProject/target/scala-2.11/sparkme-project_2.11-1.0.jar


Working directory is E:\myProject\sbtmanual
Files: 
\CONF.ENI
\mw.csv
\mw_out.csv
\pagefile.sys
\temp.rds
args: 
foo.txt
config set.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/15 14:36:21 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/09/15 14:36:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: Boern
16/09/15 14:36:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: Boern
16/09/15 14:36:22 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(Boern); users with modify permissions: Set(Boern)
16/09/15 14:36:22 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 59716.
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.56.1:59729]
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 59729.
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\Boern\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-c7ee2dab-ea00-4ae5-9f06-c6ab74f135e5
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/09/15 14:36:23 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.56.1:4041
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is C:\Users\Boern\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-2736b20a-fc90-40e8-a7ad-2d8cac8001f2\httpd-14abb177-9801-403c-9df9-84afb2e87d70
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 59746.
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/E:/myProject/target/scala-2.11/sparkme-project_2.11-1.0.jar at http://192.168.56.1:59746/jars/sparkme-project_2.11-1.0.jar with timestamp 1473942983631
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO Utils: Copying E:\myProject\sbtmanual\foo.txt to C:\Users\Boern\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-2736b20a-fc90-40e8-a7ad-2d8cac8001f2\userFiles-7849db02-01ff-40ea-9250-62b87d854f4c\foo.txt
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt at http://192.168.56.1:59746/files/foo.txt with timestamp 1473942983695
16/09/15 14:36:23 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://127.0.0.1:7077...
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20160915123633-0015
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160915123633-0015/0 on worker-20160915105800-10.0.2.15-44537 (10.0.2.15:44537) with 4 cores
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20160915123633-0015/0 on hostPort 10.0.2.15:44537 with 4 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160915123633-0015/0 is now RUNNING
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 59781.
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 59781
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.56.1:59781 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 59781)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
sc set.
argument 0 is foo.txt
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 208.5 KB, free 208.5 KB)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 19.3 KB, free 227.8 KB)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.56.1:59781 (size: 19.3 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at SparkMeApp.scala:39
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at SparkMeApp.scala:41
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (count at SparkMeApp.scala:41) with 2 output partitions
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (count at SparkMeApp.scala:41)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at SparkMeApp.scala:39), which has no missing parents
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.9 KB, free 230.7 KB)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1752.0 B, free 232.4 KB)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.56.1:59781 (size: 1752.0 B, free: 511.1 MB)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at SparkMeApp.scala:39)
16/09/15 14:36:34 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
16/09/15 14:36:37 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (BoernsPC:59783) with ID 0
16/09/15 14:36:37 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, BoernsPC, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2286 bytes)
16/09/15 14:36:37 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, BoernsPC, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2286 bytes)
16/09/15 14:36:47 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager BoernsPC:48448 with 511.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, BoernsPC, 48448)
16/09/15 14:36:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on BoernsPC:48448 (size: 1752.0 B, free: 511.5 MB)
16/09/15 14:36:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on BoernsPC:48448 (size: 19.3 KB, free: 511.5 MB)
16/09/15 14:36:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, BoernsPC): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) on executor BoernsPC: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist) [duplicate 1]
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, BoernsPC, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2286 bytes)
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, BoernsPC, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2286 bytes)
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on executor BoernsPC: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist) [duplicate 2]
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, BoernsPC, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2286 bytes)
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) on executor BoernsPC: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist) [duplicate 3]
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, BoernsPC, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2286 bytes)
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) on executor BoernsPC: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist) [duplicate 4]
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, BoernsPC, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2286 bytes)
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) on executor BoernsPC: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist) [duplicate 5]
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, BoernsPC, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2286 bytes)
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) on executor BoernsPC: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist) [duplicate 6]
16/09/15 14:36:49 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (count at SparkMeApp.scala:41) failed in 14,616 s
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: count at SparkMeApp.scala:41, took 14,694943 s
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) on executor BoernsPC: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist) [duplicate 7]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, BoernsPC): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1143)
    at boern.spark.SparkMeApp$.main(SparkMeApp.scala:41)
    at boern.spark.SparkMeApp.main(SparkMeApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/E:/myProject/foo.txt does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.56.1:4041
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\Boern\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-2736b20a-fc90-40e8-a7ad-2d8cac8001f2
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/09/15 14:36:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\Boern\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-2736b20a-fc90-40e8-a7ad-2d8cac8001f2\httpd-14abb177-9801-403c-9df9-84afb2e87d70
```

Comment: have you tried to use a fully-qualified path for the "--files" options? Also have you verified that the file is actually copied to the working directory of the workers?

Comment: thanks for your appreciated feedback! I also tried "E://myProject/foo.txt", "E:/myProject/foo.txt" and "./foo.txt" without success, although "foo.txt" is correctly copied to SPARK_WORK_DIR/app-XXX/0. It's on the same level as the submitted .JAR. What I don't get is, why the error is giving me the path of the file on the submitting windows machine?

Comment: Could you please paste the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Sure ! I feel like I messed up the "scope" somewhere...

Comment: Ok, I'm not really sure what's happening but you could try with a naive "./foo.txt"

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, but I already tried that. I even manually created a file on the Spark machine under "/tmp/foo.txt" and passed that as parameter to the programm - without success.